# Unable to change the resize handles with option

Tags: jquery-ui, jsfiddle

I have a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/AbARW/3/ where an image is initially configured to have resize handles in all four corners. When I click the button I try to change this to only one handle in the se corner, using

```
 $('button#changeHandles').click(function() {
        $('img#pelican').resizable('option', 'handles', 'se');
    });
```

But this seems to have no effect.  Does anyone see the problem?

Comment: I found the bug ticket see update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this is a known bug: [ticket #3423](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/3423)

I put together a workaround using [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and took the liberty of making your button switch the handles back and forth rather than being a one time use.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/AbARW/5/)**

```
$(function () {
    $('img#pelican').resizable({
        handles: 'ne,se,sw,nw',
        aspectRatio: true
    });

    $('button#changeHandles').click(function () {
        if ($('.ui-resizable-ne, .ui-resizable-nw, .ui-resizable-sw').is(':visible')) {
            $('.ui-resizable-ne, .ui-resizable-nw, .ui-resizable-sw').hide();
        } else {
            $('.ui-resizable-ne, .ui-resizable-nw, .ui-resizable-sw').show();
        }
    });
});
```